# Can annotations be used to keep Groovy/Grails code DRY?

Tags: grails, groovy, controller, annotations, dry

I'm using Grails 2.2.0 to stand up a website and I'm looking for best practices/advice on keeping my code DRY. This is my first use of Grails and I have some familiarity with both Groovy and Grails but am not an expert by any definition. I do come from a Java+Spring background.

I have vanity URLs as a requirement. In essence, the URI is used as a key to look up the required model. If it isn't found, redirect to the homepage. If it does exist, it will be used in the controller action's helper (as directed by the closure, executed only when present). Here is a sanitized example of my current (working) source:

UrlMappings.groovy:

```
"/$groupName/dashboard"(controller: "dashboard", action: "viewAll")
"/$groupName/dashboard/create"(controller: "dashboard", action: "createRecord")
"/$groupName/foo/$action?"(controller: "foo")
```

BaseController.groovy:

```
Group requireGroupFromUrl(Closure c) {
  if (params.groupName == null) {
    redirect(controller: "home", action: "index")
    return
  }
  else {
    Group group = Group.findByUrlName(params.groupName)
    if (group == null) {
      redirect(controller: "home", action: "index")
      return
    }

    c.call(group)
  }
}
```

DashboardController.groovy extends BaseController:

```
def viewAll() {
  requireGroupFromUrl({ Group group -> gymHelper(group)})
}

def viewAllHelper(Group group) {

  // some logic involving 'group'

  def map = [groupInstance: group, /* OTHER CALCULATED/QUERIED PARAMS*/ ]
  render(view: "/groupView", model: map)
}
```

This works. However, it seems kludgy with the need for helper methods 'n all.

From a glance, it seems that a filter could do the job, but then I need to specify which paths are to be excluded from the filter (/, /login, /register, etc) which seems to keep it tightly coupled to entries in UrlMappings.  Or I can use `uri` somehow with multiple patterns? e.g. `uri: '*/dashboard/**, */foo/**'`? How can I pass the retrieved object onward?

Could this instead be better achieved with an annotation using Around advice that annotates only the applicable controller actions? If so, can an Aspect call `redirect`? How can the retrieved object be passed down to the annotated controller action?  i.e.

```
@GroupRequired
def viewAll() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I realized last night, while starting to experiment with a filter, that the uri pattern will be difficult, as `/$groupName` is a valid path in my application.

Answer (score 2):

A Controller [beforeInterceptor](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Controllers/beforeInterceptor.html) can accomplish this cleanly:

```
abstract class BaseController {
    def beforeInterceptor = {
        if (params.groupName == null) {
            redirect(controller: "home", action: "index")
            return false
        }

        Group group = Group.findByUrlName(params.groupName)
        if (group == null) {
            redirect(controller: "home", action: "index")
            return false
        }

        // put the group into the params object
        // for use in the controllers
        params.group = group
    }
}

class ChildController extends BaseController {
    def myAction() {
        Group g = params.group

        // do things
    }
}
```